# getApplicationContext() not working for asynchronous event

Tags: android

I want to toast text entered into a texbox using an asynchronous event eg. press button. It compiles without error but nothing happens when the button is pressed. From what I have been able to gather on the forum, my context is wrong. Can someone help me? Below is the code:

```
mSendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_send);
mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
        String message = view.getText().toString();
        if (message == "bla") {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bla was entered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bye ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mSendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_send);
mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
        String message = view.getText().toString();
        if (message == "bla") {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bla was entered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bye ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

or:

```
mSendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_send);
mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
        String message = view.getText().toString();
        if (message == "bla") {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Bla was entered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Bye ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have no stack trace ?

Your code seems right, at least if it's in an Activity.

Suggestions :

- try with getBaseContext() instead of getApplicationContext()
- look for stack traces
- try with Toast.makeText(MyActivityClass.this,"Bye ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Or, better yet, just use the `Activity` as the `Context`, rather than trying `getBaseContext()` (not recommended) or `getApplicationContext()` (*really* not recommended).

Comment: Thanks, dystroy. I found the mistake higher up in the code. The call to the function had been masked out. So it was never reaching the "if" statement in the first place.